# Is this small stepped crack under window a worry?

Tags: walls, windows, brick, cracks

We recently bought a house, nothing like subsidence come up on our survey, we went for a full survey.

We have noticed a small stepped crack under the window outside the front. No evidence of any issue else where. And the window is a fairly new replacement by the old owners.

Our house is a mid stepped terrace house. Does this just need repointing or could there be a problem?

The crack is less than 2mm wide

[image: ![Cracked mortar in brickwork]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like a problem.  Mortar cracks like this in brick facing are not uncommon as a home ages and settles slightly.  A problem would be when the crack is opening up and showing significant movement.

I would, however, re-point or caulk this mortar to prevent water from infiltrating and then freezing and possibly opening this up wider.

Comment: @BillyL if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the proper way to say "thank you" is to click the up-vote arrow next to any and all answers that have helped you, and to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_. It's usually recommended to wait 24- to 48-hours to accept an answer, as it often takes that long to get a couple of good responses to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The foundations are cracked, it's probably going to get worse.

How long until it's bad enough to need attention is hard to guess.

Comment: Oh really ?! I didn’t think it was that bad

Comment: I'm not saying it's going to rapidly get worse, but it is what it is,